# JavaFX DatePicker with time

Tags: datetime, jdbc, javafx, datepicker, prepared-statement

Is it possible to also get the time using DatePicker so that I can save it to MySQL database(datetime variable) through JDBC(setDate)?

```
public class PublicClass 
{
    public static Date asDate(LocalDate localDate) 
    {
        return Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    }
}

*********

java.util.Date dateIn_Date = PublicClass.asDate(dtpDateIn.getValue());
java.sql.Date dateIn_SQLDate = new java.sql.Date(dateIn_Date.getTime());

*********

preparedstatement.setDate(9, dateIn_SQLDate);
```

My problem is that when I insert using the code above, the inserted value is just '2015-10-01 00:00:00'. How do I include the time?

Thanks.

Comment: possibly this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493097/is-there-any-date-and-time-picker-available-for-javafx

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible.  The JavaFX DatePicker is not designed for that and LocalDate objects, as in your snippet have no time information.  the [JFXtras](http://jfxtras.org/) project has date/time pickers that allow a user to pick both the date and time.  The [ControlsFx](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) project also is working on a time picker control.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613619/how-to-make-a-timespinner-in-javafx for a home-baked time picker.